# Wrong results whne looping through arraylist, and the selected type contains no fields; can't make constructor

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

I have this 2 questions. These are few of my classes. Where is my problem? I can`t automaticly make constructor, only manually and in the 1st class, I getting wrong results when loop over arraylist(sorry for my bad english)

**Test Class:**

```
    package schoolPackage;

    public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Students student1 = new Students("pe6o", 28);
        Students student2 = new Students("Iv", 15);
        Students student3 = new Students("Ivan ", 2);
        Students student4 = new Students("Ivan M", 155);
        Students student5 = new Students("Ivan Mil", 222);
        Students student6 = new Students("go6o", 12);
        Students student7 = new Students("sa6o", 1224);

        School.addStudent(student1);
        School.addStudent(student2);
        School.addStudent(student3);
        School.addStudent(student4);
        School.addStudent(student5);
        School.addStudent(student6);
        School.addStudent(student7);
        School.allStudentsInfo();

    }

}
```

**School.java:**

```
 package schoolPackage;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;

    public class School {

        private static ArrayList<SchoolClass> clasess = new ArrayList<SchoolClass>();
        private static ArrayList<Students> students = new ArrayList<Students>();

        static void addClass(SchoolClass schoolClass) {

            clasess.add(schoolClass);

        }

        static void addStudent(Students student) {
            students.add(student);

        }

        public static void removeStudents(String name) {
            Iterator<Students> studentss = students.iterator();

            while (studentss.hasNext()) {
                Students str = studentss.next();

                if (str.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    studentss.remove();
                }
            }

        }

        public static void removeSchoolClasses(String ID) {
            Iterator<SchoolClass> SClasses = clasess.iterator();

            while (SClasses.hasNext()) {
                SchoolClass str = SClasses.next();

                if (str.getClassID().equalsIgnoreCase(ID))
                    ;
                SClasses.remove();
            }

        }

        public static void allStudentsInfo() {
            for (Students stud : students) {
                System.out.println(Students.getNumberInClass());
            }
        }

    }
```

**SchoolClass.java**

```
package schoolPackage;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SchoolClass {

    private String classID;

    public String getClassID() {
        return classID;
    }

    public void setClassID(String classID) {
        this.classID = classID;
    }

    public SchoolClass(String classID) {
        super();
        this.classID = classID;
    }

    private static ArrayList<Teacher> teachers = new ArrayList<Teacher>();

    private static void addTeacher(Teacher teacher) {

        teachers.add(teacher);

    }

}
```

Comment: Don't make everything `static`!

Comment: Add the complete code, your SchoolClass and Students is missing in the above code, also format your code

Comment: Perfect English would have been "I am getting incorrect results", and it **still** would be wrong on StackOverflow **because you didn't tell us what the wrong results are**.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your method **allStudentsInfo()** in School.java i.e. use **stud** instead of *Students*

```
public static void allStudentsInfo() {
        for (Students stud : students) {
            System.out.println("ID :: "+ stud.getIdNumber()+", Number In Class :: "+stud.getNumberInClass());
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the expectation? do you want the Sorting on Student list based on NumberInClass?

Comment: No. I just want to print all the ID numbers of students, but keep getting only last number of last student in allStudentsInfo() method.

Comment: Check out the Modified code, it will print both the property of Student.

Comment: I keep getting same result - only the last object.                                              ID :: sa6o, Number In Class :: 1224. This is printed 7 times :(

Comment: I have ran the same code which you have added and for me it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted the implementation of your Student class, it's somewhat difficult to precisely know what's going on.

Based on the code fragments, you are overusing static in your code. Are you sure you understand the meaning of static? My suspicion is that your `Students` implementation also uses static variables and you are overwriting this static variable each time you create a new student and therefore you only get your last result back.

BTW: The type should really be called `Student` rather than `Students` since it represents only one...

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I couldn`t post other class due it`s keep denying my edit :( You were right, I made Student`s arguments static and that was misstake.  Thank you all guys.

Comment: If you like my answer, can you please mark it as useful?